# R: Convert Binary to Raster File

Tags: r, binary, r-raster, file-conversion, rgdal

What I intend to do is rather simple. I downloaded binary files (such as this one: ftp://ftp.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/smcd/jhuang/npp.viirs.aerosol.data/edraot550/monthly/2015/) and want to convert them into a regular raster format (such as tif) using R. The files contain gridded global data on aerosol optical thickness.

I tried to read the files using `x <- readBin(filename, "double", endian = "little")`. However, the resulting object only contains a single number. Plugging in another `what` option instead of `double` solely changes the given number but does not solve the problem.

There is no header file provided by the data source. The documentation (ftp://ftp.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/smcd/jhuang/npp.viirs.aerosol.data/edraot550/1README.txt) provides comments on Fortran and and IDL in which I am entirely unexperienced. Therefore, it would be great to do this rather simple task in R. Intuitively, the solution should be a matter of one or two commands.

Thank you for any comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this file:

```
g <- 'npp_aot550_edr_gridded_0.25_201503_201505_am.bin.gz'
```

First unzip

```
library(R.utils)
gunzip(g)
```

Now you can use `list.files` to get bin files

```
f <- list.files(pattern='\\.bin$')[1]
```

But there I'll just hard-code it:

```
f <- 'npp_aot550_edr_gridded_0.25_201503_201505_am.bin'
```

Make a template raster that matches the described resolutoon for extent and resolution.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(res=.25)
```

Save to file. The datatype sets the file size, that is how I could see that it had to be 'FLT8S'.

```
writeRaster(r, 'test.grd', datatype='FLT8S', overwrite=T)
```

Copy the header

```
file.copy('test.grd', extension(f, '.grd'))
```

Rename the file with the values

```
file.rename(f, extension(f, '.gri'))
```

Create a RasterLayer object and set the proper NA flag value

```
r <- raster(extension(f, '.gri'))
NAvalue(r) <- -999.9
```

The values are stored from bottom to top, so they need to be 'flipped'. I save them to a tif file in the same step

```
x <- flip(r, 'y', filename=extension(f, 'tif'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Robert Hijmans answer, but creating from zero a raster object:

```
library(raster)

x <- readBin('~/Downloads/npp_aot550_edr_gridded_0.25_201503_201505_am.bin','double', n = 1036800, endian = "little")

x[x < -900] <- NA

m <- matrix(data = x, nrow = 720, ncol = 1440, byrow = T)

r <- flip(raster(m, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90),direction = 2)

library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sp)

pal = brewer.pal(7,"Greens")
brks.qt = classIntervals(x[!is.na(x)], n = 7, style = "quantile")

spplot(r, at=brks.qt$brks,col.regions=pal)
```

[image]

By the way, when I read values there are -999.9, not -9999.0 as the documentation says.