# Accessing PERSIANN rainfall data files with R (.bin to raster)

Tags: r, spatial, binaryfiles, raster

I am trying to extract the rainfall data from the PERSIANN rainfall dataset using the R package R. The data comes in a binary file format (.bin). Therefore,  any help in converting the .bin files into a raster using the R package 'raster' would be very much appreciated.

The rainfall data can be found here (PERSIANN rainfall dataset): ftp://persiann.eng.uci.edu/CHRSdata/PERSIANN-CCS/daily/

I have tried using the example from: R: [R: Convert Binary to Raster File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630760/r-convert-binary-to-raster-file), but I couldn't get this to work.

This is a new rainfall dataset and very little examples/documentation for use of these files with R exists.

Answer (score 2):

The below seems to work

Create the "grd" file template. Only do this once

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(xmn=0, xmx=360, ymn=-60, ymx=60, nrow=3000, ncol=9000, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
values(r) <- 1
r <- writeRaster(r, "test.grd", datatype="FLT4S")
x <- readLines("test.grd")
x[grep("byteorder", x)] <- "byteorder=big"
x[grep("nodatavalue", x)] <- "nodatavalue=-9999"
writeLines(x, "test.grd")
```

Get the data. 1 file example -- you can of course wrote a loop to get them all

```
url <- "ftp://persiann.eng.uci.edu/CHRSdata/PERSIANN-CCS/daily/rgccs1d03001.bin.gz"
gzf <- basename(url)
download.file(url, gzf)
R.utils::gunzip(gzf)
```

Rename the bin file extension to `gri` and copy the `grd` file to match the name

```
f <- gsub("\\.gz$", "", gzf)
file.rename(f, extension(f, "gri"))
fg <- extension(f, "grd")
file.copy("test.grd", fg)
```

Create a RasterLayer; multiply to get correct min/max values. And `rotate` to get coordinates from -180 to 180.

```
r <- raster(fg) * 1
r <- rotate(r, filename=paste0("ok_", fg))

# looks ok
plot(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am clearly not familiar with the binary format, but I tried something, maybe it will help you.
First, if you didn't, look at the readme file of your data, which is helpfull to understand the data, even if it's still a bit unclear for me.

Then, you can try something with this kind of code:

```
##get the data
f <- "rgccs1d03001.bin.gz"
##unzip the data
library(R.utils)
gunzip(f)
f <- "rgccs1d03001.bin"
##read the data
d <- readBin(f, double(), n = 3000*9000, size = 4, endian = "big")
```

Beware : I am not an expert, and I don't fully understand either your data, what you want to do exactly, or how works readBin(). But since I've been able to load some data with this, maybe you can work from there. I used the parameters "double()" and "size = 4" since the readme file was mentionning 4 bytes float data, big-endian for the same reason, and the size is choosen because they mention a coverage of 3000 rows and 9000 cols.

Comment: Francois51, thanks for your reply and solution. I tried it out and I was able to get some data, but unfortunately it doesn't make much sense. The data set is daily rainfall values in mm, and the numbers I get using his method are way to large. I shall keep trying and will post something once I find a solution.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code, working with this informations : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/readBin ; it seems better to me : you have the right number of data, missing values are correctly interpreted (-9999), and the values make some sense. I just don't know what you expect exactly with the output. Here, it's a vector of 2700000 values, but I guess you would expect a dataframe?

Comment: This question keeps getting closed despite receiving the correct answer (See below and Robert Hijmans answer). Stackoverflow, by closing this question for a 2nd time (after the correct answer had been posted) you are simply depriving people the answer to this issue, if they are searching for it. I have the code and quite frankly that's all I need.

I would love to see an example of how to make this niche question even more 'focused'.....

Comment: Agreed. I would like to add a new answer based on `terra` mixing both answers